# More than one extensions do not shown in wx.FileDialog

Tags: python, wxwidgets

I tried to do the save dialog, where I should choose a file extension, when the data will be saved to.
simple code in python:

---

```
    def onSave(self, e):
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose file", self.dir, "", "*.txt|*.docx", style=wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.file = dlg.GetFilename()
        self.dir = dlg.GetDirectory()
        #do something
    dlg.Destroy()
```

---

Only .txt file is shown in file type selector. WHat is it possible to do more than one file type available to choose?
I'm using python 3.8 and the newest version of WxWidgets on Archlinux

Comment: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_dialog.html. At the ery top of the page there is an example of how to use the class. Or just check the wxPython sample code.

Comment: @Igor I did the same as in example, but it does nothing. ONly first extension is available.

Comment: please look more closely and compare you code with the code from the example on the page: `XYZ files (*.xyz)|*.xyz` vs `*.txt|*.docx`, Aso, check the remark on the page linked, right below the sample code.

Comment: @Igor But in this example, "file xxx (*.xyz)|*.xyz" is to not the same as in my code. I have to open files with more than one extension. *.xyz is one extension, and I want to add another, which is invisible to choose. I did it the same as in this example, something like "Plain text files(*.txt)|*.txt|Another type (*.docx)|*.docx" and only .txt is available to choose from the list.

Comment: did you look at the remark below the sample code?